# Please check result of derivative

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification

i am trying calculate this math derivative of [image]. I use chain rule and here is my result:
[image]

Can you check this please? I tried wolphramalpha but it give me another result:

[image]

What I do wrong?

Comment: Recall that $\tan(x)=\displaystyle\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$.

Comment: Your answer and wolfram answer are the same answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are good, they coincide exactly since
$$
\tan x  = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}
$$